# Status change by clicking yes or no word in yii2 for all pagination

Tags: ajax, pagination, yii2, pjax

In my data grid i have 2 pages . when i click on my function value to change this to net value then after refreshing it redriect me on my index page at pagination=>1. but i change pagination at=>2 .. My code of function is

```
'value' => function ($data)
            {
                if ($data->is_featured == "1")
                { 
                    $url = Yii::$app->params['application_base'].'backend/mentor/not_featured/'.$data->mentor_id;
                    $title = 'Click to remove featured attribute';
                    return Html::a('Yes',$url.$data->mentor_id,['title'=>$title],['data-id'=>$data->mentor_id]);

                } 
                else
                {
                    $url = Yii::$app->params['application_base'].'backend/mentor/featured/'.$data->mentor_id;
                    //print_r($url);
                    //exit;
                    $title = 'Click to make featured mentor';
                    return Html::a('No',$url,['title'=>$title],['data-id'=>$data->mentor_id]);
                }
            },
```

Comment: Where is this code? Post the surrounding code please.

Comment: You expect help? ... Your text is even hard to read (couldn't you at least remove your typos????) and one has to guess where that code is (part of GridView?). Don't be lazy, otherwise don't expect too much...

Comment: Please tell me that which type of code you want .. i have added the code in which i got problem ....

Comment: The surrounding code. `'value' => funtion() {...}` is part from what? The GridView? Update your question with this information please.

Comment: attribute at which i want to change the word